# My ASP.NET application does not seem to be using the style sheet for the application after permissions change

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, permissions, windows-server

I have an ASP.NET application that stopped being server by the server. I had the Sys Admin give the IIS_WPG read, write and execute permission on the root directory of the application. It appears that the permissions filtered down to all the children files and directories and the server serves the application.

However, now it displays with out the normal Master Page formatting. I am using the Default Master Page that VS provides with the default css and directory structure.

Also, my application is not executing my javascript function which is imported from another file. This worked before the permissions changes and now it does not.

Does anyone have and ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: My guess is that you are missing handlers or MIME types for .css and .js files. Which version of IIS?

Comment: Check the IIS logs for 404 errors. That would help you identify a misconfigured path, or a path with insufficient permissions to the CSS or JS file.

Comment: @Cory I believe its IIS 6. Also, could changing this directories permissions cause the handlers to become broken? What else might cause this?

Comment: @DFord: If you changed directories, it could be that the code itself is referencing a hard-coded path for the JS and CSS files, therefore you may need to edit the *.aspx files (either the Master Page if one exists, or each page itself). These paths should never be hard-coded: there are ways to reference them that won't break (`VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/JS/test.js")`, `Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/JS/test.js")`, or through a `ScriptManager`.

Comment: Sorry, i meant to say directories permissions, i did not change the directory structure. The Master page is default and it references the site.css in the Styles directory. This was never changed. Here is the link to my css `<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: @JohnFx I do not see any 404 errors in the IIS logs.

Comment: If permissions have changed, the obvious thing to check is if users are no longer allowed to read your .js and .css files. This should show up in the logs as a 403, I think. Another possibility is that you're chasing a red herring and that your problem has nothing to do with the permissions. One idea: as an experiment, copy one of your css files to the same directory as an aspx and then point that aspx to this copy. If that works, then your problem is either directory paths or permissions. If it doesn't work, it's something else.

Comment: @Jay that did not work either.

Comment: Just try if you can download the css file if you type the fully qualified path directly in the browser.

Comment: @Pleun it says im not authorized to view the page. Does this mean its a permissions issue? And if it is, which user or group needs more permissions?

Comment: Well so it is an permission issue... Is it really iis6? Cause thats a long time ago for me. Probably IIS_USR, ASPNET  or IUSR_MachineName or something like that need read and perhaps execute access.

Comment: It is IIS 6. I will try those user names or something similar.

Comment: @Pleun Thank you, it was the built in account IUSR_<machine name>. I gave that acount access and everything worked again. Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. I added it as an anwer, can you mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Just try if you can download the css file if you type the fully qualified path directly in the browser.

You did and it says not authorized to view the page

Well so it is an permission issue... Is it really iis6? Cause thats a long time ago for me. Probably IIS_USR, ASPNET or IUSR_MachineName or something like that need read and perhaps execute access